# duplicate image when sending vnstati stdout to mail

Tags: email, command-line, email-attachments

vnstati generates a png file which can be redirected to stdout, and I'm trying to mail that png image using the command below - but it is attaching 2 duplicate images instead of just 1.

Can anyone tell me why it's 2 pngs instead of just one??

`vnstati -d -o - | mail -s "Subject" email@domain.com --content-type=application/octet-stream --encoding=base64 --content-filename=image.png --attach=-`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So... the duplicate image was only appearing in Apple Mail - Gmail was only displaying one image correctly.

What fixed it was to remove the additional content-type and encoding information and let 'mail' add it automatically. The result is 1 image in Gmail and 1 image in Apple Mail.

`vnstati -d -o - | mail -s "Subject" email@domain.com --content-filename=image.png --attach=-`

Done. :)